# CMake does not set the compiler option -std to gnu17 or c++17 although I set the target_compile_features to cxx_std_17

Tags: c++, cmake

I updated the versions of GCC and CMake. After the update CMake no longer sets the right command line option for the c++ standard.

Here is how I set it:

```
add_library(project_options INTERFACE)
target_compile_features(project_options INTERFACE cxx_std_17)
```

and then I link to the project_options

```
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE project_options)
```

With GCC 8.3 (on rhel) this sets the std compile flag to `-std=gnu17`

Now it is set to `-std=c++11`

If I set the compiler globally it works as expected:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

What am I missing? Or is this a bug in the new Tools?

My System:

- GCC: 11.1.0
- CMake: 3.20.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the target property `CXX_STANDARD` to an appropriate value.

```
set_target_properties(project_options PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) and [here](https://crascit.com/2015/03/28/enabling-cxx11-in-cmake/) for further details.

Comment: but project_options is an INTERFACE! this does not work :/

Comment: Out of curiosity: what CMake version did propagate the setting? You may ask the question on the CMake mailing list in case recent CMake changes introduced this behaviour. https://discourse.cmake.org/

Comment: Thanks I cross posted my question to:
https://discourse.cmake.org/t/cmake-does-not-set-the-compiler-option-std-to-gnu17-or-c-17-although-i-set-the-target-compile-features-to-cxx-std-17/3299